# Do loop until the last row of data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a Select Case Statement within a do loop, it will operate all the way down to the last row of data (hence `lr` variable). When I run the code, the code ignores the lastrow and loops all the way down to the bottom of the spreadsheet  I have tried moving the do loop around so that `Do until lr = cells(RowNum, i + 1)` however I am getting the same error. Can someone put me out of my misery please! thanks!

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim i As Long, finalRow As Long
Dim RowNum As Long

set i = 10
lr = Worksheets("1").cells.Find("*", cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
RowNum = 2
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr")

Do Until cells(RowNum, i + 1) = lr
                Select Case cells(RowNum, "P")
                        Case Is = "1"
                        If cells(RowNum, "I").Value = "Available" Then
                            cells(RowNum, i + 1).Value = "Purchase"
                        End If
                    Case Is = "2"
                        If cells(RowNum, "I").Value = "Not Available" Then
                            cells(RowNum, i + 1).Value = "Attempt Purchase"
                        End If
                    Case Is = "3"
                        cells(RowNum, i + 1).Value = "Purchase Automatic"
                    Case Is = "4"
                        cells(RowNum, i + 1).Value = "Do not Purchase"
                    Case Else
                        cells(RowNum, i + 1).Value = "N/A"
End Select
RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop

        End If
        Next i
        
End With

end sub
```

Comment: "the loop runs an error" cannot help us to help you. It does not say too much. What error and on what row?

Comment: You compare the *content* of the cell `cells(RowNum, i + 1)` with `lr`. Change this to `Do Until RowNum = lr` (or better `> lr`). Btw, you should use a `For`-loop: `For rownum = 2 to lr`

Comment: You only `Set` objects, `set i = 10` should be `i = 10` or really 11 because you add 1 to it every time you use it.

Comment: @FaneDuru updated with more detail

Comment: What `lr = Worksheets("1")....` does return?

Comment: You have an `end if` with no `if`, `next i` with no `for` and an `end with` with no `with`

Comment: `Do Until cells(RowNum, i + 1) = lr` means to exit the loop only when `cells(RowNum, i + 1)` **value** is equal with `lr`. Try using `Do Until RowNum = lr` instead. Then, you did not post all the involved code. There are things which do not have a meaning without something obviously missing...

Comment: @FunThomas Thank you for your solution!